# How list the levels of a navisworks file in the viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

I'm trying to list the level of a building. I've load the Navisworks file and viewer is working.

Here is my page in javascript : 
http://devsteel.fr/bi/

I've found an extension to color rooms and show a level. It load successfully but nothing appear on the viewer : 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/make-shader-face-room-object-model

I've found this link to 
https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a7185a92a0a7aeb152725d5

So, how to list the levels of my building like the examples?

EDIT : I've find the dbIdif of each levels. So, how can I only show One given level?

I've try `viewer.show([12460])` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Isolating it so only that DBID will be visible

```
viewer.isolate(12460)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but .isolate() made a ghost effect.

Comment: I've found a helpful code here : https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hidding-completely-viewer-nodes-no-ghosting